# How to give a specific value to input with ' ng-model="searchQuery" '?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating an app using Ionic Framework and I'm facing a problem.

I'd like to create a search function with tags. When we click on a button, the value is given to an input.

My code :

```
<div id="rech-btns" class="padding" ng-model="searchQuery" ng-controller="RechCtrl">

  <button class="button button-outline button-balanced espace rech-text" ng-click="showDiv('Facile')">
    Facile
  </button>

  <!-- There are others buttons but I deleted them for you to see the whole code -->

</div>

<div id="rechrech">

  <label class="item item-input">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <!-- <input type="search" placeholder="Recherche..." /> -->
    <input type="search" ng-model="searchQuery">
    <!--<input type="text" text="facile" ng-model="searchQuery">-->
  </label>

  <div class="padding">
    <button id="paramrech" class="button button-outline button-balanced espace rech-text">
      <!-- the value arrives here -->
    </button>
  </div>
```

I tried to change the value with my function but it doesn't work so I'm asking you :p

My function :

```
.controller('RechCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showDiv = function(param) {
    document.getElementById('rech-btns').style.display = "none"; 
    //so when we click, this disappear
    document.getElementById('rechrech').style.display = "block";
    //this appear
    document.getElementById("paramrech").innerHTML = param; 
    //and here I don't know what to do to change what I want
  };
})
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Tell me if you don't understand :p

Comment: yes i don't understand what is your expected out put

Comment: And so I'd like that the value arrives in the searchQuery

Comment: first thing if your using angularjs you dont need document.getElementById

Comment: if you want to set an updated value to a variable you can easly do in angularjs you can use two way data binding in angularjs that will reduce your code and easy to access

Comment: try to explain your output some more detail

Comment: Well, the ng-model="searchQuery", when you type something in the search bar, it filters the data in my database and show what I want to see. If I want a cupcake, I type cupcake and I got it. But, I want this to be automatic. When we click on a button with the value cupcake, I want to see my the result of the search. But, when I do it, the value DOES go in the search bar when it doesn't show what I want to see. I don't know if it's really clear sorry :/

Comment: so you want that cupcake name to be stored in a variable in your controller am i right

Comment: well, not really because I kind of already store it and then display it in the search bar to do the "search action" but it does not work